# How to handle errors in my CustomAutorize attribute in asp.net 3.0 Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception, roleprovider

I am working on an asp.net MVC 3.0 Application. I am using using my own CustomRoleProvider 
and CustomErrorHandler by overriding default attributes.

Every thing is working fine. But ,the problem is with the exception handling.

While testing the application , tester has given invalid DB connection to test.

The result is , Custom Error Handler is not rendering Error View , instead it is routing the original path

For ex:

I am running my application as

```
Home/Index
```

It is first hitting Custom Role Provider  to fetch the roles for the application

Since , the Db Connection is not correct , it is raising exception that "Not able to Connect"

Now , Instead of routing to Error View along with this error message. It is routing to Home Controller and Index action.

```
**The code for my Custom Error Handler is as Follows**



public class CustomHandleErrorAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute    // Error handler 
    {
        public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext.ExceptionHandled || !filterContext.HttpContext.IsCustomErrorEnabled)
            {
                return;
            }
            if (new HttpException(null, filterContext.Exception).GetHttpCode() != 500)
            {
                return;
            }
            if (!ExceptionType.IsInstanceOfType(filterContext.Exception))
            {
                return;
            }

            // if the request is AJAX return JSON else view.
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest")
            {
                filterContext.Result = AjaxError(filterContext.Exception.Message, filterContext);
            }
            else
            {
                filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
                var controllerName = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
                var actionName = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"];
                var model = new HandleErrorInfo(filterContext.Exception, controllerName, actionName);

                filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
                {
                    ViewName = View,
                    MasterName = Master,
                    ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<HandleErrorInfo>(model),
                    TempData = filterContext.Controller.TempData
                };
            }

        }
        protected JsonResult AjaxError(string message, ExceptionContext filterContext)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
                message = "Something went wrong while processing your request. Please refresh the page and try again.";
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
            return new JsonResult { Data = new { ErrorMessage = message }, ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
        }
    }
```

In the above code , after setting up filterContext.Result . It is not rendering Error View as Expected.

Please correct/suggest me, where i am going wrong..

**Updated:**

public class CustomRoleProvider : RoleProvider         // Custom role provider
    {
public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
        {

```
          // Fetching roles for user from database 
    }
```

// Some other Methods

}
This is method is generating exception , since it is trying to connect to wrong connection

**Updated2:**

1) I am using Custom Error Handler for the entire controller.

2) I need to catch all the exceptions including Ajax Errors

3) I have included my code for Custom Error Handler Above

4) I am also using CustomRole Provider for entire controller

5) Here, I am trying to generate exception , by giving wrong database connection

6) I am running the URL : Home/Index

7) Before going to thatr URL, it is hitting the methods in Role Provider class since i am using it as a attribute

8) Since, i have gave wrong DB Connection , It is generating exception

9) Then, it fires on exception method of Custom error handler

10) Building the Error Model for the error view

11) But, here is the problem. Instead of rendering Error View , it is going to index method of the Home Controller.

12) But, i need Error View to be rendered here, because it has failed to connect to database and getting roles . I want furthuer execution of URL Home/Index to be stopped here.

Hope this clarifies the problem..i am running in to. please feel free to ask me for furthuer details/Clarification

Comment: I'd like to see more of the code that's causing the error. Like the controller that's using this attribute. Why do you feel the need to create your own Error Handler instead of using the one that exists already? There is an OnException method you can override on each controller, or in a base controller you have set up where you can deal with the Exception there instead.

Comment: @krillgar..I am getting exception inside my Customroleprovider method.

Comment: @krillgar..Updated my question..please check

Comment: I'm assuming that you have the attribute on the Controller Class? My biggest question is why is the user providing the DB Connection? Why is your connection string not a part of your `Web.config` file?

Comment: I am providing Database connection in the web.config itself. and yes i am using the attribute for the controller class

Comment: Do you have this in your web.config? This goes in the system.web node: `<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error"></customErrors>`.

Comment: I just have this :  <customErrors mode="On">
    </customErrors>

Comment: The error is not happening in web.config , rather in Model where it is connecting to database

Comment: Put the `defaultRedirect="Error"` in there, and that should help with it not going to your error page.

Comment: If my requirement/problem was not clear / understandable..i will furthur eloborate

Comment: The majority of your question is "why won't it redirect to your error page?". That should be your reason. If not, then there's something else in your custom attribute you don't have set up.

Comment: No.it was not working.

Comment: To solve your issue with being unable to connect to your database, that's another problem. You'd have to check on if your user from your connection string has the correct access abilities to the database you're specifying. It could also be a matter of the database not being accessible from where your code is running.

Comment: I am using custom error handler for my controller , which is catching that exception.I have mentioned my code in the question.

Comment: That Connecticvity error is raised by me intentionally to check error handling is properly working or not, it is not the actual problem

Comment: But, that Custom Handler instead of redirecting to error page it not doing it rather it is executing controller action

Comment: I still not sure how you apply the `[CustomHandleError]` filter. Do you want that your application uses it *on Home controller only* or you want use it as *global* filter (`GlobalFilters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());`). `HandleError` is designed to be able to register *multiple* filters (for example for different exceptions). One filter can handle only some specific situations. So currently *both* standard and `[CustomHandleError]` filter applied. You can use `Order` parameter for example (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1977261/315935)) to make your filter working before.

Comment: @Oleg..I am using CustomErrorHandler for all the controllers.Is there any way to find whether the exection is happening after the error has occured.For example,retrieving last error information

Comment: @Avinash: `filterContext.Exception` has class `Exception` and have all information about the exception the error has occured. You can examine `filterContext.Exception.InnerException` which can be interesting in case of `SqlException` for example. You can get `ErrorCode` by `filterContext.Exception.GetType().GetProperty ("ErrorCode")`. Is is what you asked?

Comment: @Oleg..i am getting the exception details using filterContext.Exception

Comment: @Oleg..Not exactly..that..what i mean to say..at any point of time..how we can find out..whether the application is in exception state or normal state/

Comment: @Avinash: I think if `filterContext.Exception` is not null then one have an exception case.

Comment: @Oleg..Thanks oleg..It worked for me..i am marking it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HandleError` is designed to be able to register **multiple** filters (for example for different exceptions). One filter can handle only some specific exceptions or error cases and another unhandle cases can be handled by another `HandleError`. I suppose that currently *both* standard and your  `[CustomHandleError]` filter are applied. You can set the `Order` property to an integer value that specifies a priority from -1 (highest priority) to any positive integer value. The greater the integer value is, the lower the priority of the filter is. You can use [Order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filterattribute.order%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) parameter for example (see here) to make your filter working before. More full description of the order you can find in [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.handleerrorattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx#specifying_the_order_property).

[The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1977261/315935), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5072037/315935) and [the article](http://www.aspnet101.com/2011/01/asp-net-mvc-error-handling-using-the-handleerror-filter/) for example provide small examples of usage `Order` property of `HandleError`.